# R: Make boxplot using crosstalk and ggplot2, box plot color is lost

Tags: r, ggplotly, crosstalk

I would like to make box plot using `crosstalk`, `ggplot2` and `plotly`. But I encountered 2 issues:

1. the fill color is lost in the box plot
2. I cannot remove the `All` option in the dropdown menu.

Below is my demo code.

Thanks a lot for your help.

```
sd = SharedData$new(mpg)

# Create a filter input
continent_filter = filter_select(id = "Year", label = "Year", sharedData = sd, group = ~ year, multiple = F)

# Render graph
bscols(
  continent_filter, 
  ggplotly(
    ggplot(aes(y = hwy, x = manufacturer, group = year), data = sd) + 
      geom_boxplot(aes(fill = manufacturer)), tooltip = NULL
  ),
  widths = 12
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your lost `fill` is that you mapped `year` on the `group` aes in ggplot. This can seen by just plotting the ggplot which also has no fill:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(aes(y = hwy, x = manufacturer, group = year), data = mpg) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = manufacturer))
```

[image]

To fix that map the interaction of `year` and `manufacturer` on the `group` aes:

```
library(crosstalk)
library(plotly)

sd = SharedData$new(mpg)

# Create a filter input
continent_filter = filter_select(id = "Year", label = "Year", sharedData = sd, group = ~ year, multiple = F)

# Render graph
bscols(
  continent_filter, 
  ggplotly(
    ggplot(aes(y = hwy, x = manufacturer, group = interaction(year, manufacturer)), data = sd) + 
      geom_boxplot(aes(fill = manufacturer)), tooltip = NULL
  ),
  widths = 12
)
```

[image]